# How to avoid so many “if” statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, format

I have a problem. I have side methods like:
dataWithoutFrom and dataWithoutTo and main method:

```
public Fototball getDataBetween(LocalDateTime dateFrom, LocalDateTime dateTo) {
    Footballer string = new Footballer(giocatore);
    if (dateFrom == null && dateTo == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Null!!");
    } else if (dateTo == null) {
        return dataWithoutTo(dateFrom, dateTo);
    } else if (dateFrom == null) {
        return dataWithoutFrom(dateFrom, dateTo);
    } else {
        if (Football.this.firstNode.getDateTime().isAfter(dateFrom) && Football.this.getLast().getDateTime().isBefore(dateTo)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
                string.add(Football.this.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error!");
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

How to format this code without so many IF's???
Regards

Comment: what's wrong with many IF's? as it is I dont see a problem. the question is are there going to be changes? added IF's?

Comment: First of all, you should strive for correctness, instead of worrying about the number of `if` statement. Your method is name “getDataBetween” but you’re not trying to find “data” between the datetimes but return all or through a meaningless exception `RuntimeException("Error!")`. It also would be strange if the return type “`Fototball`” is correct. Why is the variable of type `Footballer` called “`string`”?

Comment: Well, you can get rid of most of the `else`s (all but one) - but that wasn't your question.

Comment: One technique for eliminating complexity with dates in this case would be to substitute the "beginning of x" for the null `dateFrom` case and the "end of x" for the null `dateTo` case - for example if the applications is concerned with a single "season" then subsitute start-of-season and end-of-season.  This may reduce the processing complexity - but just a guess without seeing more code.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to eliminate the nested if.

```
public Fototball getDataBetween(LocalDateTime dateFrom, LocalDateTime dateTo) {
    
    if (dateFrom == null && dateTo == null) 
        throw new RuntimeException("Null!!");
        
    if (dateTo == null || dateFrom == null) 
        return dataWithoutTo(dateFrom, dateTo);
        
    if (!Football.this.firstNode.getDateTime().isAfter(dateFrom) || 
        !Football.this.getLast().getDateTime().isBefore(dateTo))
        throw new RuntimeException("Error!");
    
     Footballer string = new Footballer(giocatore);
     for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) 
         string.add(Football.this.get(i));
     return string;
}
```

Comment: only if `dataWithoutFrom` is same as `dataWithoutTo`

Comment: You are right.  I misread it.

Comment: It might make sense to refactor both of those methods into a single method.